# Can we detect whether a link was clicked within a DIV that has a jQuery.click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering whether there is an easy way to detect a click on a link that appears within a div on which I want to handle clicks...

So, there is an simple example of HTML code:

```
<div class="checkmark">
    <div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="label">Checkbox label possibly <a href="/random" target="_blank">with an anchor</a>.</div>
</div>
```

So in this example, I use a set of `<div>` tags to create a checkmark. The "box" is where I show a little square and when checked, also show the checkmark (a red cross, for example.)

To make the checkmark work as expected, I use jQuery and capture mouse clicks on the main `<div>` tag:

```
jQuery("checkmark").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery("box", this).toggle("checked");
});
```

Pretty easy, that works great (the "checked" class is enough to show a checkmark since that can be defined using CSS.)

However, as we can see in the example, the "label" includes an anchor. If I click the anchor, the jQuery I just presented runs, but the anchor does nothing. If I remove the stopPropagation() and preventDefault() the anchor gets clicked, but the checkmark is toggled too.

What I'm wondering is: is there an easy way to check whether the propagation would trigger the anchor and in that case just ignore the click in the "checkmark" code?

Something like that:

```
jQuery("checkmark").click(function(e){
    if(!(anchor.clicked()))  // how do we do this?
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery("box", this).toggle("checked");
    }
});
```

P.S. I do not know whether there are anchors in the label. So the discovery has to happen in the click() function (unless there is a better setup and that "if" could happen differently).

Note: here I show a `target="blank"` parameter. In the real deal I will actually open a popup, but that doesn't really make a difference here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what [**`event.target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) is for.

For example, in this case:

```
if($(e.target).is("a")) { 
   // It was the anchor element that was clicked
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2MLDS/58/)

Comment: Ah! I've seen that before. It put it in my code and it works perfectly. (Only I use the ! in the condition and avoid the default behavior of the `<div>` tag.)

Comment: It may be more correct to do `$(e.target).is("a") || $(e.target).parentsUntil("a")` depending on specification

Comment: Agree with last comment, or maybe verify $(e.target) and $(e.target.parentNode)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the event delegateTarget property to see which DOM element triggered the event.

```
if($(e.delegateTarget).is("a"))
    // execute code
```

Comment: What's the different between the `delegateTarget` and the `target`? I tried with the `target` as shown by @null and it worked as expected...

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this handler:

```
jQuery("checkmark a").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

It will stop the click event from bubbling from the link to the div, so the link will be activated, and the event never reaches the div where it would be stopped.

Comment: I cannot know that there is an anchor and actually assume that in most cases there isn't. I guess this works too because if there are no anchors, no click() function gets attached...

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Yes, if there is no anchor element the selector won't match anything and the jQuery object will be empty. Using a method like `click` on an empty jQuery element will just do nothing.